# Bind/map response to more than one object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. I have a controller ActionResult that has various incoming requests from various parties. I want this ActionResult to figure out what type of request it is, validate it, and perform several RedirectToAction.

My problem is that while I know how to bind a single model/object to an ActionResult and have the framework automatically map the variables from the request to that model's properties, I don't know how to achieve the same "automapping" functionality when I need to map the same request to several models that are completely separate from each other inside a single ActionResult. I am unable to determine what models are contained inside the request until I map them and validate them, by checking if the models' properties are not null.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should really create different Actions. Since the models that are passed in are different you cannot bind them to the same action.

Of course, what you could do is create different action methods, and from there on just call a single method that contains all of your logic

Comment: The thing is that its not really up to me whether to use different actions or not. I'm working on a replacement for a legacy system, where there are all kinds of different POST and GET requests sent to the same url. In other words, I don't know what is being sent to the same action until I parse the request and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the different model classes you could create an interface that they implement, and use this interface as the model type in your controller method.

Then you could create a custom model binder and do your checking of properties there.